# How to append timestamp to jar in spring boot gradle project?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, jar, java-15

How to append a timestamp to jar in the spring boot Gradle project?

```
./gradlew build
```

Creates jar `app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`, how to create jar with timestamp

```
app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-2020-11-09.02-30.jar
```

-------- Gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.5.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
bootJar {
    archiveFileName = "app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-"+new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd.HH-mm')+ ".jar"
}
```

Tested with gradle `6.6.1` and spring boot plugin version `2.3.4`